# Count Files Present on FTP

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ssis, biztalk, ssis-2012, biztalk-2013

I have an FTP site which is used as a receiving location by a BizTalk Application.

I need to count if any files have been present form a long time on  the FTP site?

How do I complete this task in SSIS.

Comment: @ERIC-i have tried developing the package ,where in i can check , if files present or not by using a script task.But how do i count those files ,is the task.